# What is $P(\min\{X, Y\} = 1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $y=1,2,3$ and $x=0,1,2$ where $P(X=x, Y=y) = k(2x+3y)$

I need to find $P(\min\{X, Y\} = 1)$.

I thought I need to use that the CMF of the minimum is $1-P(X)$, and maybe to find k by doing derivative on the equation and to sum it up to 1?
would love any direction on this.

Comment: "*and maybe to find $k$ by doing derivative on the equation*"  Why derivatives?  No... don't bother.  Just note that the sum of all possibilities should add up to $1$.  That is to say... $P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=2)+P(X=0,Y=3)+P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=2)+\dots+P(X=2,Y=3)=1$.  Use that to find $k$.  Complete by then finding $P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=1,Y=3)+P(X=2,Y=1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $P(X=x, Y=y) = k(2x+3y)$

$\sum_{(x,y)}P(X=x,Y=y) = k(0+3) +k(2 + 3) + k(4 +3) + k(0+6) + k(2+6) + k(4+6) + k(0+9) + k(2+9) + k(4+9) = 72k = 1$

Hence $k = \frac{1}{72}$

Now, $P(\min(X,Y)=1) = P(X=1,Y=2,3) + P(X=2, Y=1)$